# Lumen - Class url does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I am using Lumen to create a website, and while my controllers, routes, and views are well configured, I get an error when I try to use the redirect function in a controller.

This is the error code :

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 736: Class url does not exist

in Container.php line 736
at ReflectionClass->__construct('url') in Container.php line 736
at Container->build('url', array()) in Container.php line 631
at Container->make('url', array()) in Application.php line 203
at Application->make('url') in Redirector.php line 39
at Redirector->to('http://opentracker.local/token/archived', '302', array(), null) in helpers.php line 246
at redirect('http://opentracker.local/token/archived') in TokenController.php line 51
at TokenController->unarchive('clickid')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(TokenController), 'unarchive'), array('clickid')) in Container.php line 507
at Container->call(array(object(TokenController), 'unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid')) in RoutesRequests.php line 567
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(TokenController), 'unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid')) in RoutesRequests.php line 534
at Application->callLumenController(object(TokenController), 'unarchive', array('1', array('as' => 'token.unarchive', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid'))) in RoutesRequests.php line 507
at Application->callControllerAction(array('1', array('as' => 'token.unarchive', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid'))) in RoutesRequests.php line 475
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array('1', array('as' => 'token.unarchive', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid'))) in RoutesRequests.php line 460
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array('1', array('as' => 'token.unarchive', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid'))) in RoutesRequests.php line 434
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('1', array('as' => 'token.unarchive', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@unarchive'), array('attribute' => 'clickid'))) in RoutesRequests.php line 367
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php line 610
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 368
at Application->dispatch(null) in RoutesRequests.php line 313
at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

My route is well recognized, (you can see it transformed as it should in the error).

Here is the code that I use in my controller :

```
public function unarchive($attribute){
    Token::query()->find($attribute)->update(['is_archived'=>0]);
    return redirect(route('token.archived'));
}
```

I also uncommented the following from boostrap/app.php :

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
```

Is there a problem using the function `redirect()` with Lumen ? I tried both `redirect(route())` and `redirect()->route()`, and they gave the same result.

Comment: @Gal, thank you for your idea, but as I told in the last paragraph, both `redirect(route('token.archived'))` and `redirect()->route('token.archived')` gave the same result.

Comment: yeah didn't notice anyway it seem like a known bug of lumen according to github - [redirect() doesn't work, Lumen 5.2](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on 5.2 there is an issue open for this.

[Lumen - Github Issues - redirect() doesn't work, Lumen 5.2 #315](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/315)

You can use the `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` directly if needed. (from workaround link below):

```
return new RedirectResponse('login');
return RedirectResponse::create('login');
```

[Possible workaround from Github Issue](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/315#issuecomment-173017125)

Comment: Thank you, the workaround will do while waiting for a fix from the team.